# Spritekit touchesEnded Lag

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I'm making a game with spritekit and there is a noticeable 100-200ms lag between touches began and touches ended.

Is there any way I can speed this up? I need to use touches ended (to calculate a vector ray between the starting and stopping points of the users touches.

```
-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

        touch_start_pt = location;
    }

    touching = true;
}

-(void) touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
        CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];

        double distance = sqrt(pow(location.x - touch_start_pt.x, 2) + pow(location.y - touch_start_pt.y, 2));

        if(distance > 2 && touching && !paused){
            [self impulsePlayer:location];
        }
    }

    touching = false;
}



-(void) impulsePlayer : (CGPoint) location{
    touching = false;

    player.physicsBody.velocity = CGVectorMake(0, 0);

    double dx = location.x - touch_start_pt.x;
    double dy = location.y - touch_start_pt.y;

    CGVector impulse_vector = CGVectorMake(dx*main_impulse_divisor, dy*main_impulse_divisor);

    [player.physicsBody applyImpulse:impulse_vector];
}
```

LOGS:

```
2014-03-23 02:50:26.000 Impakt[2398:60b] began
2014-03-23 02:50:26.532 Impakt[2398:60b] ended
2014-03-23 02:50:29.149 Impakt[2398:60b] began
2014-03-23 02:50:29.648 Impakt[2398:60b] ended
2014-03-23 02:50:34.368 Impakt[2398:60b] began
2014-03-23 02:50:34.815 Impakt[2398:60b] ended
```

Comment: This does not happen usually. Please add the code for your touchesBegan and the touchesEnded method

Comment: This doesn't seem like it should cause a problem. Can you use NSLog in the touchesBegan and touchesEnded methods and then show the logs with their timestamps in the question?

Comment: It's actually pretty consistently ~550ms

Comment: And you are just tapping the node? Because, you could just be 'lingering' :P

Comment: Most certainly. It's extremely frustrating haha

Comment: Well, I cannot see any problem in the code... I believe this has something to do with your development environment... Like the hardware u are using. For instance, look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526371/touchesendedwithevent-how-to-work-around-the-delay-before-it-fires

Comment: I'm testing using my iphone 5s ios 7.0.4, it is not a trackpad issue as I've already read about in that question

Comment: have an active gesture recognizer? They delay touch events...

Comment: @LearnCocos2D oh duh - yes. Write as answer and ill accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most UIGestureRecognizer instances delay forwarding touch events until they "recognized" that their gesture hasn't been, well, recognized. That will lead to toucheBegan and/or touchesEnded messages being delayed.

You can change this behavior via [delayTouchesBegan and delayTouchesEnded](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIGestureRecognizer/delaysTouchesBegan) properties of the gesture recognizer instance(s).